# How to bind List<X> to ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have 2 ViewModels - User and Reminder.

```
public class UserViewModel
{        
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Your name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }


    [Display(Name = "Your reminders")]
    public IEnumerable<ReminderViewModel> Reminders { get; set; }
}

public class ReminderViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Time")]
    public TimeSpan Time { get; set; }


    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Frequency of repair")]
    public string Frequency { get; set; }
}
```

My add-view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "Test"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @ViewBag.Status

            <ul style="list-style: none;">
                <li>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)
                </li>

                   ???????????? // Reminders
                <li>
                    <input type="submit" value="Add" /></li>
            </ul>

}
```

My question is: how can I bind this `IEnumerable<ReminderViewModel>` in my View?

I want to achieve situation, where user can put some reminders (selecting Time and Frequency) many times, before send click.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to change it to `List<ReminderViewModel>`. In order to get proper model binding you must be able to select the objects using an index value.

Then in your view:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Reminders.Count(); i++)
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Reminders[i].Time)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Reminders[i].Time)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Reminders[i].Time)

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Reminders[i].Frequency)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Reminders[i].Frequency)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Reminders[i].Frequency)
}
```

If `Reminders` is initially null, you'll need to initialize it with one or more `ReminderViewModels` in your action:

```
var model = new UserViewModel {
    Reminders = new List<ReminderViewModel> {
        new ReminderViewModel()
    }
}
return View(model);
```

Or you can do this in your `UserViewModel`'s constructor:

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    public UserViewModel()
    {
        Reminders = new List<ReminderViewModel> {
            new ReminderViewModel();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, but what if `Model.Reminders` is null, and user want to add 3 `Reminders`? Then, should I use `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Reminders[1].Time)`, `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Reminders[2].Time)`, etc?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following:

First add a reference to the model in the top of the view like this:

```
 @model UserViewModel
```

Including your namespace.

Change your collection to user a list so it can be indexed and model binded like this:

```
         @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Reminders.Count(); i++)
         {
            @Html.LabelFor(m => Model.Reminders[i].Frequency)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Reminders[i].Frequency)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model.Reminders[i].Frequency)
            @Html.LabelFor(m => Model.Reminders[i].Time)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Reminders[i].Time)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model.Reminders[i].Time)
         }
```

This in your model:

```
 [Display(Name = "Your reminders")]
 public List<ReminderViewModel> Reminders { get; set; }
```

You also need to change your Begin form to set it to post like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "Test", FormMethod.Post))
```

Finally you need to implement the post like this taking the model as a parameter:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(UserViewModel model)
{
    // Do processing here
    return View(model);
}
```